# CSS animating button issue - during fade in animation of hover the rest of the buttons move

Tags: css, button, navigation

I am creating a vertical navigation and have already made the CSS properties for the buttons.

The hover properties are faded in using:

```
-webkit-transition:all .1s;
-moz-transition:all .1s;
-o-transition:all .1s;
-ms-transition:all .1s;
```

However, because the hover button is larger than the static button, during the animation the stack of buttons move. is there anything I can do to stop this?

The full code looks like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>link 2</a>
        <a>link 3</a>
    </form>
</div>

#nav {
position:absolute;
margin-top:96px;
margin-left:30px;
height: 450px;
width: 140px;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";}

#nav a {
background:url(Images/Button.png);
height:28px;
width:130px;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
color:#C60;
text-decoration:none;
background-position:center;
margin:auto;
display:block;
position:relative;
line-height:190%;
}

#nav a:hover {
background:url(Images/Button%20Hover.png);
height:34px;
width:140px;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
color:#C60;
text-decoration:none;
margin:-3px;
z-index:2;
line-height:220%;
text-indent:-10px;
-webkit-transition:all .1s;
-moz-transition:all .1s;
-o-transition:all .1s;
-ms-transition:all .1s;}

#nav a:active {
background:url(Images/Button%20Hover.png);
height:34px;
width:140px;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
color:#C60;
text-decoration:none;
margin:-3px;
z-index:2;
line-height:210%;
text-indent:-10px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS transform method instead of scaling with `font-size`, `margin` or `line-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/KSZsH/4/

Comment: how would I then move the hover image left by 3px?